# Is the Map referenced in this class safely published?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

Will threads that call `IsItThreadsafe.getValue(...)` get an up-to-date value from the Map referenced by the variable `IsItThreadsafe.map` (assuming the exact usage scenario implemented in `IsItThreadSafe.main(...)`?

```
public class IsItThreadSafe {

    private Map<String, String> map; 

    public synchronized void setMap(Map<String, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public synchronized String getValue(String key) {
        if (this.map == null) {
            this.map = new HashMap<>();
        }
        return map.get(key);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        IsItThreadSafe sharedObject = new IsItThreadSafe();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    String key = String.valueOf(i);
                    String value = sharedObject.getValue(key);

                    if (value!=null) {
                        System.out.println("key = " + key + " value = " + value);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();

        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                Map<String, String> mappedData = new HashMap<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    mappedData.put(String.valueOf(i), String.valueOf(i + 1));
                }

                sharedObject.setMap(mappedData);
            }
        });
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that it should work correctly unless the `setMap` caller continues to modify the map it passed to `setMap`. It should forget about this map once the `setMap` is called. Such version would be more safe in general:

```
public synchronized void setMap(Map<String, String> map) {
    this.map = new HashMap<>(map);
}
```

Of course though your code is correct, it doesn't mean that the code is optimal. In particular if you are not going to put new values into the map, it's possible to get rid of synchronization every time you query the value. For example, you may use `AtomicReference`:

```
private final AtomicReference<Map<String, String>> map = new AtomicReference<>(); 

public void setMap(Map<String, String> map) {
    this.map.set(new HashMap<>(map));
}

public String getValue(String key) {
    Map<String, String> m = this.map.get();
    // loop is necessary if setMap(null) call occurs
    while (m == null) {
        // Use CAS to avoid possible overwrite of concurrent setMap() call
        m = new HashMap<>();
        if(!this.map.compareAndSet(null, m))
            m = this.map.get();
    }
    return m.get(key);
}
```

Here synchronization is replaced with volatile read which is in general much faster.

Comment: Why do you think, you don’t need to copy the `Map` within `setMap` when you are using an `AtomicReference`? Besides that, the `getValue` method is unnecessarily complicated. If the `Map` is `null`, there is no need to create a new `HashMap`, that map will be used only for `get` calls which are already known to fail. If the `Map` is `null`, we can simply return `null` as we already know that that’s the result of calling `get()` on an empty `HashMap`. Once you got rid of that obsolete update operation, a simple `volatile` variable would be sufficient.

Comment: @Holger, "Why do you think" - I don't think so, updated. Overly complicated - possible for this particular case, though probably necessary in some more complex case when `new HashMap<>()` is replaced with some map with default values. Well, probably I stick too much to the OP's code. Write your answer, so OP will see a simpler alternative :-)

Comment: Setting a non-empty map as a side effect of a `getValue(…)` call, doesn’t sound like a reasonable scenario to me. I don’t want to write an answer that is only addressing a side aspect here. The main question regarding the thread safety has been answered by you.